# LaTeX: Cite, but don't reference

Tags: latex, bibtex, bibliography

I'm producing a set of documents in LaTeX, and I would like to provide a single, global bibliography page for the whole set. This is because each document is page-limited: I don't want to take up space with references at the bottom of each one.

This means in each case, I would like to cite in the text, but not produce a reference at the end. I am using bibtex/natbib to handle the referencing.

Simplest example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\bibliographystyle{/usr/share/texmf/bibtex/bst/natbib/plainnat.bst}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
In \citet*{MEF2010} I described the method.
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}
\end{document}
```

How can I do this? Essentially I just want it to cite correctly:

```
In Bloggs, Blagg and Blog (2010) I described the method.
```

But not add a references section at the end. Any ideas?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Instead of using `\bibliography{bibliography.bib}` you can try `\nobibliography{bibliography.bib}`.

You still need to enter the path so it can make the cross-references.

Comment: Great - does exactly what it says on the tin. Note that you need to add the bibentry for this to work:      \usepackage{bibentry}

Answer (score -2):

It happens due to missing packages. If you want to resolve the problem then enable the automatic installation packet. After that,First, you run  the BibTeX file and generate the Pdf file (instead of pdfLatex file) and then pdfLatex to Pdf